# php calling a parent constructor

Tags: php

```
class Dad {   

    private $par1;

    function __construct(int $par)
    {
        $this->par1 = $par;
    }
}

class Child extends Dad {

    private $par2;

    function __construct(int $par1, int $par2)
    {
        $this->par2 = $par2;
        parent::__construct($par1);
    }
}
```

Having this code I have a question about calling `parent::__construct($par1)` in the child class. Should we call it before initializing variables or after initializing them like in my example or it does not matter ?

Comment: In this example, there is no need to call the parent constructor at all...  It completely depends on your situation and if your child conflicts with or needs to override anything in the parent constructor.

Comment: In this case, it does not matter since both constructors do completely different things. Order matters if both set the same property for example, and you want a particular result. Maybe you want your child to overwrite something the parent would set, or maybe you need to overwrite a parent's default protected property before the parent constructor calls a method.

Comment: I changed a little bit, removing par1 from class `Child`. I imagine a situation when the parent class keeps variables which are not kept in `Child` class

Comment: It's the same thing. Usually, since the parent don't know anything about the children, you can call it first, so that the children is able to override any propriety. But really, in your example it's indifferent.

Comment: The "should" is entirely dependent on what each class does, and what you want them to do. There is no right answer to your question.